# Single JSP with different Action Class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a single JSP page, which is used to upload files. This page has to be used in many different location in my application, but each time I use this page my action class for the form is different.

I am using Struts 2 and Hibernate. Could anyone please suggest on how to implement this.

Given below is my JSP code:

```
  <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="left"><s:url
        action="" id="idfileValidate" escapeAmp="false"></s:url> <input
        type="button" class="btn"/></td>
</tr>

...............

<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="left"><input type="button" class="btn"/><s:url
        action="" id="idfileUpload" escapeAmp="false"></s:url> <input
        type="button" class="btn" id="buttonUpload"/>
    </td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

The action in both the `<s:url>` tag will be different different calling locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give action name in url as following

```
 <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" border="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="left"><s:url
        action="fileValidate" id="idfileValidate" escapeAmp="false"></s:url> <input
        type="button" class="btn"/></td>
</tr>

...............

<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="left"><input type="button" class="btn"/><s:url
        action="fileUpload" id="idfileUpload" escapeAmp="false"></s:url> <input
        type="button" class="btn" id="buttonUpload"/>
    </td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

You need to mapped that action in struts.xml as following

```
<action name="fileValidate" 
            class="com.action.struts2.validatefileaction" >

<action name="fileupload" 
            class="com.action.struts2.fileupload" >
```

Try this

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but if i mention the action class name in the jsp how can i use the same jsp in different location with different action class?

Comment: I think now this jsp is used in both class if you click on first button  it call to file validate action and if you click on second button then it call file upload action then this jsp is used for two different action. Now what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

The only action name is variable in your JSP. Create a field in each action class or in the base class as

```
String actionName;
//getter and setter
```

then use this in JSP

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="left"><s:url
        action="%{actionName}" id="id%{actionName}" escapeAmp="false"></s:url> <input
        type="button" class="btn"/></td>
</tr>
```

it will dynamically substitute the action name for each action returning a result with this JSP.